# Display extra rows (conditionally) separated by column name

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle11g

I have a table like this:

```
initial   confirmatory  confirmatory1  confirmatory2  confirmatory3
3.4       true          3.6            4.9            7.4
2.1       false         null           null           null
```

I want to generate a database view like this:

```
initial  confirmatory_n  confirmatory_value
3.4      1               3.6
3.4      2               4.9
3.4      3               7.4
2.1      null            2.1
```

For the rows that have `confirmatory` as false, I need to display the row 1 time. For rows that have `confirmatory` at true, I need to display the data 3 times in three different rows, with an extra column identifying which value is displayed.

I've been searching for some time, but can't seem to find relevant results. I always get stuck when trying to show `confirmatory_n`. So, I don't really have an sql samples of what isn't working because I feel I'm so far off. BUT, I did create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fc39/1/1) that might be helpful. Any help would be great.

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select initial_value, 1 as confirmatory_n, confirmatory1 as confirmatory
from results t
where confirmatory = 1
union all
select initial_value, 2 as confirmatory_n, confirmatory2 as confirmatory
from results t
where confirmatory = 1
union all
select initial_value, 3 as confirmatory_n, confirmatory3 as confirmatory
from results t
where confirmatory = 1
union all
select initial_value, null as confirmatory_n, initial_value
from results t
where confirmatory = 0;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8edd3d/10).
If your tables are very large and performance is a concern, then there are other approaches that only scan the table once.  However, this method is usually sufficient.

Comment: Beautiful. Just what I was looking for. And thanks for the fiddle!

Answer (score 2):

Another UNPIVOT solution:

```
WITH src ("INITIAL", confirmatory, confirmatory1, confirmatory2, confirmatory3) as (
    SELECT 3.4, 'true', 3.6, 4.9, 7.4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2.1, 'false', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
), dta as (
select "INITIAL"
     , case upper(confirmatory) when 'FALSE' then "INITIAL" end confirmatory
     , confirmatory1
     , confirmatory2
     , confirmatory3
  from src
)
select *
 from dta
 unpivot (confirmatory_value
     FOR confirmatory_n IN (CONFIRMATORY  AS null,
                            CONFIRMATORY1 AS 1,
                            CONFIRMATORY2 AS 2,
                            CONFIRMATORY3 AS 3));
```

Comment: Very nice, I thought immediately that mine solutoin was more complex than really needed.

Answer (score 1):

UNPIVOT solution

```
WITH src ("INITIAL", confirmatory, confirmatory1, confirmatory2, confirmatory3) as (
    SELECT 3.4, 'true', 3.6, 4.9, 7.4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2.1, 'false', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    "INITIAL",
    confirmatory_n,
    confirmatory_value
FROM (
    SELECT
        "INITIAL",
        CASE WHEN confirmatory_value IS NOT NULL THEN confirmatory_n END confirmatory_n,
        CASE WHEN confirmatory_value IS NOT NULL THEN confirmatory_value ELSE "INITIAL" END confirmatory_value
    FROM
        src
        UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS (
            confirmatory_value FOR confirmatory_n IN (confirmatory1 AS 1, confirmatory2 AS 2, confirmatory3 AS 3)
        )
    )
GROUP BY
    "INITIAL",
    confirmatory_n,
    confirmatory_value
ORDER BY
    confirmatory_n;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may well not be the most efficient solution (especially for arbitrary values of *n*), but you could write a series of `UNION` selects to accomplish this. Works in Oracle 12c.

Edit: edited to suit your fiddle.

<del>Edit2: `UNION ALL` is more performant.</del> My solution requires `union` to filter out the duplicate rows where confirmatory is false. A `union all` solution would be more performant.

```
select initial_value,
    case when (confirmatory = 1 and confirmatory1 is not null) then '1' else null end confirmatory_n, 
    case when (confirmatory = 1 and confirmatory1 is not null) then confirmatory1 else initial_value end confirmatory_value
from results
UNION 
select initial_value,
    case when (confirmatory = 1 and confirmatory2 is not null) then '2' else null end confirmatory_n, 
    case when (confirmatory = 1 and confirmatory2 is not null) then confirmatory2 else initial_value end confirmatory_value
from results
UNION 
select initial_value,
    case when (confirmatory = 1 and confirmatory3 is not null) then '3' else null end confirmatory_n, 
    case when (confirmatory = 1 and confirmatory3 is not null) then confirmatory3 else initial_value end confirmatory_value
from results
```